# How to make final local variables non nullable?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The code below produces the error String? cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

```
Some function() {
  try{
   ...
  final userData;
  userData = json.encode({'token': _token, 'userId': user_Id, "expiryDate": _expiryToken });
  prefs.setString("userData", userData);
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
}


}

    Future<bool>tryAutoLogin() async{
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        if (!prefs.containsKey('userData')){
          return false;
        }
        final extractedUserData;
        if (prefs != null){
      extractedUserData = json.decode(prefs.getString("userData")) as Map<String, Object>;
      final expiryDate = DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate']);
      if(expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now())){
        return false;
      }
      _token = extractedUserData['token'] as String?;
      user_Id = extractedUserData['userId'] as String?;
      _expiryToken = extractedUserData['expiryDate'] as DateTime?;
      return true;
      }
      return false;
      }
```

The line where there is decoding of json produces the error even after i added the line to make sure prefs is not null. What is the problem?

Comment: 1. You don't show any `final` fields here, just `final` local variables. 2. This has nothing to do with `final` variables.  You call `json.decode(prefs.getString("userData"))`, but [`json.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html) expects a non-nullable `String` argument, and [`prefs.getString`](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getString.html) could return `null`.  You need to check the result of `prefs.getString` first (e.g. `json.decode(prefs.getString("userData") ?? "")`.

Comment: The error seems to persist even after checking the result of prefs.getString (i.e `if json.decode(prefs.getString("userData)))" {}`)

Comment: The code you listed in your "i.e." remark is not syntactically valid, so I don't know what you actually did.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your earlier comment. How then do I check the result of prefs.getString?

Comment: Looking at your code again, you'll probably want to use `json.decode(prefs.getString("userData") ?? "{}")` since you unconditionally cast the result to a `Map`. (Unconditionally casting the result of `json.decode` is also a potential (but separate) problem.)

Comment: `json.decode(prefs.getString("userData") ?? "{Some code}"}` also gives "The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244289/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-richie-eloh).